# How to read a file properties present in remote linux directory from windows through a java program?

Tags: java, windows, linux

I have a directory in a remote Linux system from where i want read all files metadata( file name,size,owner etc) from my windows system through a java program.

Comment: I'd suggest you have a look at a SSH library to allow you remote access into the Linux file system

Answer (score 0):

You need someway to connect to the Linux file system using SSH, SAMBA, NFS... If you map the Linux file system to a local drive using SAMBA you can read remote files just as you would local files.  You may need to use java.nio.file.Files in Java 7 to get advanced file properties (like the owner).